# How can I get hieroglyphics in my MiKTeX 2.9 TeXworks application?

Tags: fonts, miktex, texworks

I am to write an essay which involves the use of several mathematical hieroglyphs (e.g. 1, 10..., 1,000,000, +, -, Fractions). I have tried very hard to follow (relatively) technical instructions online. Is there not a simple way to just download hieroglyphs?

It all seems quite complex for someone who isn't very used to LaTex or programming. Any help in the simplest form would be very much appreciated!

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Try the `hieroglf` package, here is a simple example,

```
% trypmhg.tex    Test Poor man's Hieroglyph fonts
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hieroglf}
\begin{document}
\pmglyph{\Hthousand\Hmillion\Hten\Hone}
\pmglyph{3}
\end{document}
```